# Best way to handle environment specif fields in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

We have one microservice that will be deployed on two different environments(A and B).
There are some common fields and also some are specific to the environment.

Example:

`SomeEntity` for environment `A` have only `name` and `age` and their `validation`.
`SomeEntity` for environment k have only `dept` and `experience` and their `validation`.

There are some fields that are common in both the environments.

**We don't want to create two different Entities for both the environment because there are only 2-3 fields that are specific to the environment and 23-25 fields are common.**

Actually, we are looking for some `design pattern` or `tool` which handle this situation the in the best way OR any inbuilt feature in `Hibernate` or `Spring framework`.

Can someone guide what could be the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: This sounds like a strange design. Why for the same micro-service you are having different DB structures, is it that you are using same service for different purposes in each environment.

Comment: Actually, one MS will be used by two different clients, in that case, there are some different fields for the same `entity` as I mentioned in Question.

Answer (score 1):

To reuse Entities that share common fields you can use for example `@javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass`

> Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the
>   entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate
>   table defined for it.

Example:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseSomeEntity {

    @Id protected Integer id;
    @Column private String validation;
    //and your other 25 common fields
}


@Entity
public class SomeEntityEnvA extends BaseSomeEntity {
    @Column private String name;
    @Column private String age;
}

@Entity
public class SomeEntityEnvB extends BaseSomeEntity {
    @Column private String dept;
    @Column private String experience;
}
```

Comment: Will I need two repositories in this case if using `spring-data-jpa`?

Comment: For this example yes, you need for each Entity one spring data repository.

Comment: Eventually, this will lead to duplicate the code at repository level...Isn't there any clean way?

Comment: You can look into `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue` if you want to use only one table.